# Is there an equivalent to the mod_pagespeed Apache module for IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, mod-pagespeed

Is there an equivalent to [`mod_pagespeed`](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/module.html) Apache module but for IIS?

Comment: Maybe you could try running your stuff through an apache proxy to see how much benefit you could get.

Comment: Have you found an answer or is this still an open question? I also need this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[IISpeed](http://www.iispeed.com) is a full-featured pagespeed port to IIS. It requires a paid license for production servers to avoid showing a banner, but it is free to try out.

Full disclosure: I am one of the people working on the port. So I will not push this further than mentioning the port.

Answer (score 5):

There aren't any solutions that do exactly what mod_pagespeed does at this time. There are several individual packages you could use to match most of the functionality.

- The product @alirobe mentioned ([aptimize](http://www.aptimize.com/)) does many of them.
- [YUI Compressor](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/) (.Net port) works on JavaScript and CSS minification
- IIS (version 5.1 and newer; though much easier to configure in IIS7+) can be configured to do GZIP compression for static and dynamic files
- You can set Expires headers in IIS for static files, and in back-end .Net code for dynamic pages
- .Net 2.0 can do some script combining with explicit configuration via the `<asp:ScriptManager>` control
- .Net 4.0 has even more script combining abilities and can do more with less configuration. ([example discussion of some of the new features](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2009/11/23/asp-net-4-0-scriptmanager-improvements.aspx))
- UPDATE: .Net 4.5 further extends [script combining with minification](http://abhijitjana.net/2011/10/06/bundling-and-minification-in-asp-net-4-5/).
- Scott Hanselman wrote [The Importance (and Ease) of Minifying your CSS and JavaScript and Optimizing PNGs for your Blog or Website](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20ScottHanselman%20%28Scott%20Hanselman%20-%20ComputerZen.com%29) that lists many other individual packages that can be combined.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a direct `mod_pagespeed` replacement but does some work towards reducing the number of requests, minifying and bundling JS and CSS.

It even automatically provides lossless compression of PNG-images and creates sprites of your background images. See the [RequestReduce library](http://requestreduce.org/).

(not tried it myself)

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

Not right now, at least.

Do keep in mind, however, that `mod_pagespeed` is an automation of the best practices of web caching and speeding and you can manually set those up. [PageSpeed Extension](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html) and [YSlow extension](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) are both very helpful to understand what should be optimized.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a free one, but there is : http://www.aptimize.com/

update: Of course, if you're using any other automated deployment tool, you could do quite a bit by integrating commandline tools into the build batch script. [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/Build-script/) is probably your best practice reference there. You can also use server-side tricks like [HttpCombine.ashx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/HttpCombine.aspx).

Comment: This is an old post! Aptimize is now RiverBed, and I woudn't recommend them any more. These days, I'd use cloud services such as https://cloudflare.com, or free proxies like nginx to handle all optimization.