# alternative for mod_pagespeed for IIS

Tags: iis, mod-pagespeed, expires-header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an equivalent to mod_pagespeed appache module but for IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106706/is-there-an-equivalent-to-mod-pagespeed-appache-module-but-for-iis)

Is there an alternative for mod_pagespeed for IIS? I want to do some smart-caching and set the expires headers in a smart way.